# Как ограничить ввод даты в календаре?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Имеется такой календарь:

```
<div class="mt-4" >
    Дата рождения:
    <input type="date" name="birth_date">
</div>
```

Как мне ограничить ввод даты чтобы можно было записывать даты с 1850 года по 2022?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<div class="mt-4">
  Дата рождения:
  <input type="date" name="birth_date" value="2012-12-01"
    max="2022-08-25" min="1850-01-01">
</div>
```

Дата рождения:
          
    
Используй атрибут max

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо большое